# Android - indexed list with clickable elements

Tags: android, listview

I'm trying to have [this kind of listview](http://eshyu.wordpress.com/2010/08/15/cursoradapter-with-alphabet-indexed-section-headers/)
but instead of red images named "person", I want to have a clickable image.

Unfortunatly, with this implementation we can't custom each view to set a ClickListener on each image item.

Any ideas to change that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check below ..

[Tutorial1](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-custom-listview-tutorial-part-1)

[Tutorial2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1655322/apply-custom-listview-for-a-cursoradapter)

[Tutorial3](http://www.workreloaded.com/2011/02/android-extending-cursoradapter-for-custom-listview/)

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom ListAdapter and then you can access the Images of you Listadapter as shown in the answer of this link:
[Need help to delete selected item from listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5881665/need-help-to-delete-selected-item-from-listview/5881722#5881722)